# DateTime to "Time" in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, datagridview, datagrid

Good morning!
I have a Form which has a DataGridView with a few time informations that I have to show it on a label. 
But as I can see, my label (and DataGrid) have Date and Time included (and I only need the time on my DataGrid and label).

I know visual studio c# doesn't has a style that converts DateTime only to "Time", but I don't know how to format these datas only as Time to show it on my label.

What should I do to:
Format this DateTime only to show Time (on my DataGrid) and then appears only as Time on my label as well (this label retrieves the DataGrid information).

Comment: WPF DataGrid != WinForms DataGridView. Which one do you use? please tag your question accordingly

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set DefaultCellStyle

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Column with time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It solved 95% of the problem.
Well, how would I show only the time on my label which retrieves the values from the DataGrid?

Comment: string value = DateTime.Now.ToString(); label1.text = value.Split(' ')[1];

Comment: I made a single adjustment 
Since "value" would be the result of my DataGrid.

Thank you for your help!